# chrome app and jquery, object has no property, how to?

Tags: jquery, properties, google-chrome-app, document-ready

there is a `getVolume()` method on youtube api

also, on a youtube page there are 2 player types that might load, a flash based one and a html5 one

if you `console.log(document.getElementById("movie_player").getVolume());`

you will get the current player volume

arriving to my issue, if i do

```
setInterval(test, 3000);
function test() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("movie_player").getVolume());
}
```

in the `contentscript.js`, the flash based video returns the volume ok, but not the html5 one

i get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getVolume'`

i was thinking that i'm not waiting for the page to load properly before i run the code, but the timeout should take care of that (the timeout is for testing purposes only).

so, any ideas why the code will work only when the flash player is present, but not the html5 one, even though the code works if i type it directly in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in the [Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) of chrome extensions. Content scripts execute as if there was no other JS on the page, they just have access to the dom. The getVolume method on `#movie_player` will have been added by some JS on the page but as far as the content script knows, that JS never executed and so that method isn't available.

The real question is....why does it work when you are using the flash version? In that case "#movie_player" is an `<embed>` instead of a `<div>`.

I tried executing

```
console.dir(document.getElementById("movie_player"));
```

from the content script and the web page when I was using the html player and upon inspecting the div I was able to see the added methods when I looked at the one executing from the console.

However... when I did the same thing with the flash player and tried to inspect the  props I couldn't see the added methods either way (I couldn't find the "getVolume" method in the embed props (on the page itself) EVEN though I could call it).

So I think I answered your question but raised another...

Comment: i don't think the props are interfering or anything. I see what you are saying that the `getVolume()` is not on the flash version :).

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully explain better. I am saying I don't think .getVolume should be accessible from the content script at all. I think the fact that you can access it sometimes (with the flash version) is a bug

Comment: i was thinking the same thing about the flash

Comment: i figure out some things, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@steven is wright. the contentscript and the webpage script are two isolated worlds.

there is a way going around this by injecting a script file into the webpage

what works for me:

`contentscript.js`

```
$(function() {
    console.log('Content script');

    injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL('scripts/injected.js'));
});

function injectJs(link) {   $('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+link+'"/>').appendTo($('head')); }
```

make another file `injected.js`, or whatever. this page will have access to the webpages js.

in my case

```
function main() {
    console.dir(document.getElementById('movie_player').getVolume());
}

main();
```

i found that i needed to add `web_accessible_resources` in the manifest and remove `run_at` key from the `content_scripts` entry

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        "scripts/injected.js"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "styles/main.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/jquery.js",
                "scripts/injected.js",
                "scripts/contentscript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": false
        }
    ],
```

Google might block this hack in the feature, or embrace it.

good luck